# Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataConfiguration.mongoCustomConversions

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I m getting this error on startup where i was trying to run custome queries for mongodb. I followed the https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-mongodb-example/ tutorial for this code

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataConfiguration.mongoCustomConversions
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.cmc.citizen.app.CitizenAppApplication.main(CitizenAppApplication.java:19) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:479) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:428) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:140) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataConfiguration.mongoCustomConversions
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:509) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:498) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:421) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:140) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.getReturnType(OnBeanCondition.java:517) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:505) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.deducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:498) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$Spec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:421) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:140) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 17 more
```

Implemenatation of the Custom Repository

```
public class UserProfileRepositoryImpl implements UserProfileRepositoryCustom{

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public UserProfile findUserProfileByEmail(String email) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("email").is(email));
         return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, UserProfile.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, which caused by non compatible versions of mongodb driver, for now, latest and correct one's bellow

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.2.5.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.11.2'
implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:2.2.5.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 0):

when i removed  the below dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb-parent -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

and added the below dependency the issue got resolved

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the complete dependenceies i used in the pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Worth noting that adding `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` automatically means you add `spring-data-mongodb` which is implicitly a dependency of the first dependency.